# Calculate when a queue will run full given it's input / output rate and capacity

Tags: queueing-theory

I just came across an interesting question:

- let's say we have a security waiting line at an airport which can physically provide space for 3500 passengers at the same time
- we know that the personnel at the entrance will let in 30 new passengers per minute (avg) into the waiting line but they do so in batches of 10 passengers at the same time (so 10 passengers every 20 seconds)
- the personnel at the exit will let out 15 passengers per minute but in average (processing time here is linear)

Obviously as the exit rate is slower than the entry rate at some point the physical capacity of the waiting line would get reached. The question would be at what point in time or after how many passengers will that be the case?

I find it hard to formulate the problem mathematically. Any hints to some useful theory would be appreciated :-)

Cheers!

Comment: Since there only one discontinuous part of the problem the number in line is linear at the end of each $20$ second interval.  You want to get to the point that the next batch fills the line.

Comment: @RossMillikan makes sense, so in that case I would argue that the growth of the waiting line is linear (probably f(x)=150x) and the maximum physical capacity is a constant function g(x)=3500? Then the point that the next batch fills the line would be at f(x)=g(x) -> 150x=3500 -> somewhere after 23 minutes?

Comment: It is linear on the average, but it comes in steps of $10$.  I don't know where the constant $150$ comes from.  You should define the unit of time you are using, which appears to be minutes.  What is the increase in one minute?  Then if you are at $3490$ at the end of a $20$ second interval the next slug of $10$ fills the queue